# Install Ubuntu/Win8.1 dual boot with UEFI and 4 primary partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 8.1 in my Acer V3-572G-75CA. The partition situation is the following:

A. 600MB: recover partition

B. 300MB: system EFI partition

C. 914GB: Windows 8.1 partition

D. 15.83GB: recover partition

Of course I have to disable UEFI boot for start the Ubuntu Live USB. But then? I can create an extended partition for / and /swap, but I need to free a primary partition, isn't it?
Can I delete partition A and/or B?

Comment: With UEFI you have gpt partitioning not the old MBR(msdos) partitioning with the 4 primary partition limit. With gpt the default limit is 128 partitions, but you can add more. Use Windows tools to shrink the Windows partition, make really good backups of Windows & efi partition and install Ubuntu with Something Else option. Install Ubuntu in UEFI option not CSM/BIOS. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system YOu may have to enable password to allow UEFI boot. Never lose that.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the hard disk has gpt partitioning and not the mbr, so I'm allowed to create up to 128 primary partitions.